# Convert Content inside div to UL li

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I have some very old server side code that creates pagination links

```
<div class="pagination ">
    <span class="previous"></span>
    <span class="current">1</span>
    <a href="/article/the-hub?i=&amp;page=2">2</a>
    <a href="/article/the-hub?i=&amp;page=2" class="next">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way with jquery to convert all the content within the div.pagination block to be ul li elements ?

Each a tag would nee to remain, and quite possibly the span tags also.

Any ideas greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to write code. If you know how, that's the "easy" way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var $ul = $("<ul>");
$(".pagination").children().each(function()
{
    var $li = $("<li>").append($(this));
    $ul.append($li);
});
$(".pagination").append($ul);
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/5TZgb/

While we might intuitively think that we are re-creating the DOM elements, we are not. This code simply wraps the Div's children with `li` tags, and re-places the elements in the DOM.

If you want a more specific selector, you may try:

```
$(".pagination span, .pagination a").each(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with jquery, though it would be definitely more advisable to actually re-write the html.

However, if you want to do the conversion with jquery, whilst retaining all tags, the folllowing will work fine.

### **EXAMPLE**

- http://jsfiddle.net/8DsZA/

---

### **CODE**

```
//select the original pagination div
var container = $('.pagination');

//prepare a new list container
var newContainer = $('<ul></ul>');

//iterate through all the children within the container and wrap them with a <li> tag
container.children().each(function(i) {
    var item = $(container.children()[i]).clone().wrapAll("<div/>").parent().html();
    newContainer.append('<li>'+item+'</li>');
});

//take out the old content
container.empty();
//add the new html structure
container.append(newContainer);

//give the old div a new class 
container.addClass('paginationContainer');

//swap out the pagination class to the new 'pagination' container
container.removeClass('pagination');
newContainer.addClass('pagination');
```