# jquery missing line after convert div into ul and div content into li

Tags: jquery, html, css

This post helped a lot but i am still having issues that cant solve by my self.
[Convert Content inside div to UL li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270413/convert-content-inside-div-to-ul-li)

I need to convert this code

```
<span class="pagination" id="pagination">
  <a href="#" title="1">1</a>
  " 2 "
  <a href="#" title="3">3</a>
  <a href="#" title="4">4</a>
</span>
```

Into this

```
<ul class="pagination" id="pagination">
  <li><a href="#" title="1">1</a></li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li><a href="#" title="3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="4">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I made some changes to the script but i have issues with the "2".

```
$(".pagination").contents()  // wraps quotation marks as elements
$(".pagination").children()  // misses " 2 "

var $ul = $("<ul class='pagination' id='pagination'>");  //added to keep class and id
$(".pagination").contents().each(function(){             
    var $li = $("<li>").append($(this));
    $ul.append($li);
});
$(".pagination").replaceWith($ul);                       //replaced span with ul
```

Thanks and sorry for not been able to solve it by my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a fiddle with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7x2m89z0/

```
var pagination = $(".pagination");
pagination.contents().each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim()) {
        $(this).wrap('<li>');        
    }
});
pagination.replaceWith($('<ul>' + pagination.html() + '</ul>'));
```

Here, each element is looked at. If it's empty, it will be ignored, otherwise it will be put in a `<li>` . The last line is from Tambo.

Comment: I know, but what you mean? should I wrap the "2" before the <a>??

Comment: @TyraPululi I changed my answer, did you see my edits?

Comment: So far this is working great, still need to chage one thing but Its working great.

Comment: Ok Its working perfect now, the only thing that I dont fully understand is .trim()...

Comment: .trim() gets rid of all non-printable characters like white spaces and line breaks. When you get the contents(), you will get text nodes only containing a line break. These result in empty li-tags. The if statement says, if any text is left after the trim, do the li-wrapping. So a string containing a whitespace like " " will result in "", so the if will result in false and not wrapping the empty text node.

Comment: If you got a JS console, you can try the following: !!"a". This results in true. !!" " will also result in true, because it is not empty. !!"" will result in false, because it is empty. The !! is an implicit typecast to boolean, by using 2 negations.

Comment: Thanks for the explication, now I understand what I was missing before, It was wrapping all characters within contents().

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `nodeType` and length of `nodeValue`.

```js
var $ul = $("<ul class='pagination' id='pagination'>");  $(".pagination").contents().each(function() {   
    var $li;
    if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim().length > 0) {
        var txt = this.nodeValue.replace(/"/g, '');
        $li = $("<li>").append(txt);
    }
    if (this.nodeType === 1) {
        $li = $("<li>").append($(this));
    }
    $ul.append($li);
});
$(".pagination").replaceWith($ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="pagination" id="pagination">
  <a href="#" title="1">1</a>
  " 2 "
  <a href="#" title="3">3</a>
  <a href="#" title="4">4</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var pagination = $(".pagination");
pagination.find("a").wrap("<li></li>");
pagination.replaceWith($('<ul>' + pagination.html() + '</ul>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="pagination" id="pagination">
  <a href="#" title="1">1</a>
  " 2 "
  <a href="#" title="3">3</a>
  <a href="#" title="4">4</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but getting the same result, "2" still not wraped within <li>